# How can I use debug_kit when my API return json

Tags: json, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

I have a cakephp app and my requisition take a lot time to return a answer - 1,5s. The problem is because all my endpoints return a json response and debug_kit just return rendered HTML. What I can do to debug this and see where my app are taking all this time to compile?.

Comment: Use the history tab to view details for previous requests: **https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3.x/en/index.html#using-the-history-panel**

Comment: This history panel just works to html response.  I alredy tried make this works, but no success. (sorry if I say something wrong, im new in developer world).

Comment: It works with every request unless you're doing something "bad" in your app (like dying in a controller to echo data). By default DebugKit runs on all requests and collects data, which is being saved in the middleware layer when the response is being passed back through that layer (that is basically after a controller returned its data).

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: How is this related to Xdebug?

Comment: I want know where my application are slow. But when I open the broswer the icon of debug is not showing in the bottom right-hand corner. Im was thinking this is because json response and not html.